# Проверка существования канала discord py

Tags: discord.py

Необходимо сделать проверку существует ли канал, как это можно реализовать? (P.S. Я делаю своего бота для создания резервных копий сервера)

Comment: в блоке try-except берешь этот канал по id, имени. Ну ты понял

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
try:
    # код поиска канала
except:
    # тут код, выводящий сообщение об ошибке
```

Данный код будет срабатывать при любой ошибке.